# cannot use YetiForce 5.2.0 after successfully install on MAC OS

Tags: php, macos, crm

i'm trying to install Yetiforce 5.2.0 from YetiForceCRM-5.2.0-complete.zip

on my MAC (MacOS Catalina) in localhost using Web Server XAMPP with the latest version which is support PHP 7.3.10

i have changed the configuration php.ini using this:
https://github.com/YetiForceCompany/YetiForceCRM/blob/5.2.0/tests/setup/php_dev.ini

and when i set it up and install it, it redirected to the dashboard with error message

```
 Class '\App\YetiForce\Shop\Product._YetiForceInstallInCloud' not found
```

and i cannot do anything, can't click every menu and everything

You can see the screenshot of error here:
[image: error]

i have searched that error from google and found nothing

What am i doing wrong here?